# Using unique() method when generating a list of options in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I need to generate a list of options in my form from a column called `product_name` in my database. I do so in the blade template like so:

```html
<select name="product" >
    <option value="" disabled>Click to select</option>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
 <option value="{{$product->product_name}}">{{$product->product_name}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

And the controller is as follows:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

This has worked well so far, however I am having more and more rows of `product_name` in my database as my product range grow, as each row is unique for its description and not its name. Thus, there are a few duplicate options in my form.

I understand that Laravel has a `unique()` method for collections. In this case, in each iteration of `@foreach`, I get a string as an option and therefore `unique()` cannot be used.

What other ways are there in Laravel for me to filter duplicated data?

Comment: Please update your question with the controller code so we can take a better look at the problem.

Comment: Hi! I have updated my question with the relevant controller code

Comment: You can use `distinct()`. i.e. `$products = Product::query()->distinct()->get();` or `$products = Product::query()->distinct('product_name')->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your query for the product name and product description column and fetch the result like this-

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::select('product_name', 'product_description')
        ->orderBy('product_name') 
        ->groupBy('product_name', 'product_description')
        ->get();

    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Updated the query with order by.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just tried this. I was able to successfully remove duplicates of the product names. If I were to sort it, I just add ->sort() is that correct?

Comment: You can add this for ordering the result- ->orderBy('column', 'desc')

Comment: I have updated the answer please take a look and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: It works very well! Thank you so much! 
I'm guessing `unique()` isn't the correct way to go about most of such queries then.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it worked for you. You can use distinct when only one column is required as unique field.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pluck;

```
public function index()
{
    //Use pluck for selecting only specific column. You can take multiple columns as 
    well.
    $product_names = Product::pluck('product_name');
    $products = array_unique($product_names);
    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::pluck('product_name', 'product_name')
                       ->toArray();

    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

That will return a unique product names